# Vagrant - Page timeout trying to access index.php

Tags: apache, vagrant, lamp

I've just setup Vagrant using Scotch Box (http://box.scotch.io/) and got everything installed and running with no errors however when I try to go to the IP of the local server, it just times out.

This is my Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.hostname = "scotchbox"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]

end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: It turns out that my Vagrant Host only network adapter is getting a 169 address and it wont let me change it.

Comment: Tried that, many times.

Answer (score 0):

May be you already figured out, In case anyone facing similar problem it could be because you are under proxy and you need to setup "No Proxy" for your vm network ip[In your case 192.168.33.10]

For example from my Firefox I have added the following and then it started running.

```
localhost, 127.0.0.1,192.168.33.10,whatever-i-want.local
```

Here is how you can access it in Firefox

[image]